# How to fetch users data in firebase specifically

Tags: java, android, firebase

I'm developing an app in which each user must log-in first then they are able to add some objects . every objects they create will be save on firebase . but i want to separate user's obeject ! for example if user A save X and user B save Y , they must only access to their objects(user A must only have access to X) , but i don't know why anybody adds anything others have access to it ! got any idea?

Answer (score 1):

in order to achieve your criteria , add an child attribute to your object node called user (the user who added that object) and then you could do a filter while requesting the data this way :

```
DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Object");
Query query =  mDatabaseReference.orderByChild("user").equalTo("the_user_name").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

 @Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
for(DataSnapshot datas: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
   //here you get your object data

    }
 }
   @Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

  }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to ensure that users can only access their own data, have a look at Firebase's server side security for [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#authentication), or for [Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security). These allow you to determine what data each user can access by specifying rules that are enforced on the server, so that they can't bypassed by any malicious client.